# Multicolor line with Core Graphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to draw a bar that has 4 color segments (not a gradient - 4 distinct colors).  Those 4 UIColors are stored in an array (I have debugged and checked that those colors are properly set).  For some reason, This loop only draws the first color (at the correct width).  This class inherits from UIView and is being invoked via

```
TopBar* bar = [[TopBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.frame.size.width, 20)];
[self.view addSubview:bar];
```

The drawRect is as follows:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
NSLog(@"draw rect");
[super drawRect:rect];

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

NSInteger fullBarWidth = self.frame.size.width;
NSInteger individualBarWidth = fullBarWidth/self.barColors.count;
NSInteger currentColorIndex = 0;

CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, self.frame.size.height);
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapButt);


for (UIColor *color in self.barColors)
{
    NSInteger currentDrawLoc = currentColorIndex * individualBarWidth;
    currentColorIndex++;

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, currentDrawLoc, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, individualBarWidth, 0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx,color.CGColor);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, individualBarWidth, 0);
```

You meant to say:

```
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentDrawLoc + individualBarWidth, 0);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.  I'll accept this when I can in 5 minutes